# Why username of Annotate(blame) is not same to author of commit in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, git-blame

when I use git annotate in IntelliJ IDEA, the username of author of some lines is not same to author name of this commit, like this pic:

[image: wrong authors]

As you can see, `fan.qp` and `Qp` is not same, why so?

When I use bash or SourceTree to run `git blame`, the two names are the same.
Is this a error of IDEA?

Comment: Do you have a `.mailmap` in your code? (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame#_mapping_authors)

Comment: Could you please right-click on gutter View | Names | and see whether Full Name is disabled? if so, please enable it and check whether the behavior stayed the same.

Comment: @VonC No，I don't have a `.maimap` in my idea and my project code

Comment: @RuslanKuleshov Thanks, but what is gutter View | Names, I can't find this in my IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: Can you see the pic which I uploaded, I cannot see it whatever I upload it

Comment: @ricklee I have re-formatted the question, with the image now included.

Comment: @ricklee please right click on a name on a left side of an editor (Annotate/blame area) and then go to View -> Names

Answer (score 22):

You can change how it's displayed just like @Ruslan Kuleshov said –

Right-click on gutter > View > Names

[image: Right-click on gutter > View > Names]